# $2x+|\cos(x)|$ is one - one

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to prove that:
$$2x+|\cos(x)|$$ is one- one.

I started from the definition.
$$f(x)=f(y)\implies
 2x+|\cos(x)|=2y+|\cos(y)|
\implies 2(x-y) = |\cos(x)|+|\cos(y)|$$
When both $|\cos(x)|$ and $|\cos(y)|$ are positive or both are negative, then I could arrive at a contradiction. But I couldn't proceed when they have opposite signs. Also it's not a differentiable function, so couldn't apply the derivative test for monotonic functions.
Kindly suggest how to proceed, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $2x+|cos x| =2y+|\cos y|$ with $x >y$. Then $2(x-y)=|\cos y|-|\cos x| \leq |\cos y -\cos x| =|x-y| |\sin t|$ for some $t$ between $x$ and $y$ (by Mean Value Theorem). Hence, $|\sin t| \geq 2$ which is absurd. Similarly $x<y$ also leads to a  contradcition, so we must have $x=y$.